# Getting around, numpy objects mismatch error in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy, mismatch

I'm having a problem with multiplying two big matrices in python using numpy.

I have a (15,7) matrix and I want to multipy it by its transpose, i.e. AT(7,15)*A(15*7) and mathemeticaly this should work, but I get an error :

*ValueError:shape mismatch:objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape*
I'm using numpy in Python. How can I get around this, anyone please help!

Comment: @agf: there's only one way to get the transpose in Numpy and it's hard to get wrong. The error message about broadcasting tells enough about the problem; if the OP hadn't transposed the matrix/array, they'd get an "objects not aligned" error, not this one.

Comment: @larsmans Thanks, didn't read closely enough.

Answer (score 14):

You've probably represented the matrices as arrays. You can either convert them to matrices with `np.asmatrix`, or use `np.dot` to do the matrix multiplication:

```
>>> X = np.random.rand(15 * 7).reshape((15, 7))
>>> X.T * X
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,15) (15,7)
>>> np.dot(X.T, X).shape
(7, 7)
>>> X = np.asmatrix(X)
>>> (X.T * X).shape
(7, 7)
```

One difference between arrays and matrices is that `*` on a matrix is matrix product, while on an array it's an element-wise product.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! larsmans it worked!! the asmatrix function helped and also didn't know the * impact on arrays and matrices.

Comment: Also, in newer (`>= 1.5`, I think?) versions of numpy arrays have a `dot` method, so you can just do `X.T.dot(X)` instead of `np.dot(X.T, X)`.